# Add to Playlist Eloquent - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I am creating a 'Add to Playlist' function for my cocktail app. The user will be able to add Cocktails to a Playlist. This is a many to many relationship.

**Cocktail.php**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class cocktail extends Model
{
    protected $primaryKey = 'idDrink';
    protected $fillable = ['strDrink', 'strCategory', 'strGlass', 'strInstructions', 'strIngredient1'];

    public function playlist()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Playlist::class);
    }

    public function favourite()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Favourite::class); 
    } 

}
```

**Playlist.php**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class playlist extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['name', 'description'];

    public function cocktails()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Cocktail::class);
    }
}
```

I have a 'Add to Playlist' button on the cocktail, that has a name of {{ $cocktail-idDrink }}. When the user clicks that button, a modal pops up with the list of available playlists that are also links with a name of the {{ $playlist->id }}. I am trying to connect these 2 some two, so when the playlist button is clicked, the cocktail is added to that playlist.

I know I need some sort of form on the Add to Playlist button, but am not sure how to achieve this. When I add a form to the button, I get a 'No Message' error.

**Add to Playlist Btn**

```
<button type="submit" href="#" class="primary-btn add-btn" name="{{ $cocktail->idDrink }}" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalCenter"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i>Add to Playlist</button>
```

**Modal Playlist Btn**

```
@foreach($playlists as $playlist)
  <div class="modal-body">
    <a name="{{ $playlist->id }}" href="#">{{ $playlist->name }}</a>
  </div>
@endforeach
```

[Playlist Modal Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pukFc.png)

[Add to Playlist Button Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PmAE1.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if am getting this right, but I think the best solution is to work with the relationship as stated, a cocktail belongs to a playlist. Therefore, you'll need to add cocktails to a playlist. So probably would have a flow like:

- A listing of all the playlists with the add cocktail button on each
- Then at click add cocktail, show your pop up modal here which will fetch all the cocktails,
- You can use select2 here or if your are using vuetify, use v-autocomplete component with multiple prop enabled.
- After this, you will select all the cocktails to add to your playlist at click save, you attach all the selected cocktails.

Comment: I think you have it the wrong way round. I think the OP has a list of cocktails and wants to hit a button to add to a playlist, which will then open modal with the list of all available playlists.  So his issue is knowing which cocktail was clicked.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this a few different ways, most people would probably use an AJAX request.  However it can be done with a form by doing something like the following:-

```
@foreach($cocktails as $cocktail)
<a class="primary-btn add-btn" href='#' data-toggle="modal" data-target="#cocktail-{{ $cocktail->id }}">i class="fas fa-plus"></i>Add to Playlist</a> 
<div class="modal" id="cocktail-{{ $cocktail->id }}">
    <div class="modal-body">
    <form action="/your-route" method="POST">
        @csrf
        <input type='hidden' name='cocktail' value='{{ $cocktail->id }}'>
        @foreach($playlists as $playlist)
            <label >
            <input type="radio" name="playlist" value="{{ $playlist->id }}">
            {{ $playlist->name }}
            </label>
        @endforeach 
        <button type="submit" class="primary-btn">Add To Playlist</button>
    </form                                
    </div>
</div>
@endforeach
```

This approach would create a modal for each cocktail, or you can also do it with a single modal by using some JS to update the hidden `cocktail` field's value.

Hopefully this will give you an idea on how to do it.